# Javascript object payload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet of code which is running with the success call of an $.ajax jquery call.

```
success:function(results){
    if(options.payload)
    {
        eval("AddReview."+options.payload+"("+results+")");
    }
}
```

The results variable can contain html and does not seem to want to pass through to the function. Is this the correct way to do this or can you think of a better way? This method basically allows me to interface the jquery $.ajax functionality with variable function payloads. Or in this case Object function payloads.

Comment: Why can't you just use `AddReview[options.payload](results);`?

Comment: What does `results` look like?

Comment: @Blender I'm assuming a string given his example.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst: Right, but if it looks like `'foo', 'bar'`, none of the answers will work.

Comment: @Blender that is true, but we can still work around that if he provides us with examples.

Comment: Whenever you use eval: There IS a better way ;)

Comment: @SebastianG It is naive to assume that all usages of `eval` are bad/wrong. There a plenty of scenarios where it is the best/only solution. It's not evil if it's used safely and appropriately.

Comment: @flem It's naive and rude to call my experience and the opionion of most Javascript experts/authors I know naive. Probably there are scenarios, however, I don't know one and never had to use eval.

Comment: All very good answers to my question and I have more than solved it.

Comment: How is OP David's solution more complete than mine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there's a better way. There's no need for `eval` in this case:

```
if (options.payload) {
    AddReview[options.payload](results);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Objects are essentially associative arrays. Use this.

```
AddReview[options.payload](results);
```

As [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender) mentioned, if `results` is a list of string arguments such as `'hello', 'stack', 'overflow'` you can do this.

```
var addReview = AddReview[options.payload];

var args = $.map(results.split(','), function(arg) {
    return $.trim(arg).substr(1, $.trim(arg).length - 2);
});

addReview.apply(addReview, args);
```